# Hide a row and the row above when the range in the row is 0

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel 2013 I would like to hide a row and the row above it when the row has a value of 0 in Column C to Column H. Column C to Column H is a merged cell. For example if C7:H7 has a value of 0 I would like to hide row 7 and row 6. The entire range for this C6:H53. Every other odd row has either text or a 0 in it. When the odd row number has a 0 I would like to hide that row and the even row number above it. For another range (C77:H233) in the workbook I have a working macro that hides a row with a 0 value but I have been unable to figure out the correct code to hide the row plus the row above for the range of C6:H53.

```
Row #/COL A     COL B   COL C   COL D   COL E   COL F   COL G       COL H 
4 SALES/GROSS MARGIN                             
5                       Sales     Costs     GP%    Bdgt %    Bdgt Diff    
6 Siding                0       0     #DIV/0! #DIV/0!    
7                       0.00                                            
8 Tile                  0       0     #DIV/0!        #DIV/0!    0.00                                    
9                       0.00                        
10 Tools & Hardware    330     -315    0.045454545        #VALUE!    
11                     Two sales to Joe Roofing and Riviera Ridge Roofing with 
                       no budget. No comment from managers.                    
12 Windows              0       0    #DIV/0!        #DIV/0!    
13                      0.00                                             
14 Fabricated Products  0       0    #DIV/0!        #DIV/0!    
15                      0.00
```

In the above example with the value of 0 in row C7:H7 I would like to hide rows 6 & 7, with the value in C9:H9 0 then hide rows 8 & 9, with the value in C13:H13 0 then hide 12 & 13, with the value in C15:H15 0 then hide 14 & 15, etc. I want Rows 10 & 11 displayed as C11:H11 has text in it.

The last of many codes I have tried without success is

```
Sub HideSales()

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("Sales")
If Sales.Address = "C7:H7" Then
If cell.Value = 0 Then
Rows(6:7).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
Rows(6:7).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

End Sub
```

VBE doesn't like several rows- the first row, Sub HideSales(), is highlighted in yellow, both rows that have Rows(6:7) are highlighted in red.

Not sure where to go to next.  Gave up on 2 other sites - could not even get the question to submit.

Comment: Your 'For Each' loop doesnt have a 'Next' at the end of it; one of your 'If' loops also doesnt have an 'End If' at the end of it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are worrying about 'the row with zero and the row above it'. Doesn't every row you want to hide have a 0 or a 0.00 in column C?

Answer (score 0):

If you filter for zeroes in column C (from row 6 down) then collect and store the the range, you should be able to release the filter and hide the rows with the zeroes.

```
Sub hide_zeros()
    Dim rZEROs As Range

    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    appTGGL bTGGL:=False

    With Worksheets("Sheet5")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        .UsedRange.Offset(5, 0).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        With .Range(.Cells(5, 3), .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
            Debug.Print .Address(0, 0)
            '.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=0", _
                        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=0.00"
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    Set rZEROs = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                End If
            End With
            .AutoFilter
            If Not rZEROs Is Nothing Then _
                rZEROs.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End With
    End With

bm_Safe_Exit:
    appTGGL
End Sub

Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
    Application.EnableEvents = bTGGL
    Application.DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
End Sub
```

Before:

[image: Filter for Zeroes and Hide Before]

After:

[image: Filter for Zeroes and Hide after]

Comment: to Jeeped - YOU ROCK!!!!!!!  I made a couple of tweaks to my formatting and it worked perfectly. Awesome! I have no idea how you know all that but wow.  Thank you thank you thank you.